# Автоматическое нажатия клавиши

Tags: javascript, button

Есть приложение на JS. В нем есть кнопка, нажатие которой так же привязано к клавише R. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, что бы сразу после загрузки приложения автоматически один раз нажималась клавиша R?

Comment: Выдерните из кода функцию нажатия "клавиши" и пропишите её отдельно например, запуская в том числе после загрузки вашего приложения. И, хорошим тоном было бы приложить к вопросу и код ваш.

Comment: В том то и дело, код не мой, и я там вообще толком ничего найти не могу, и потому проще всего реализовать это имитацией нажатия R

Comment: Представляете, вы не можете найти нужного имея код перед глазами, а мы должны подправить этот код даже его не видя... Вам не обязательно копировать сюда весь код приложения, можно просто найти функцию вашей кнопки и этого было бы достаточно, так явно охотнее вам помогли бы.

Comment: Да, но я надеялся, что можно просто вписать пару строк в конце кода, которые отвечали бы за нажатие клавиши R))

Comment: логика функции с кнопкой - нажать на кнопку > вызвать функцию.
Вызовите функцию после загрузки